# Solving Math Problem with Code/Tool; Identifying Problem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to define a problem I've got, and then figure out the easiest way to solve the problem.

I've got three totals I want to meet without going over, by filling in a number of known values.

250, 360, and 420 are the totals.

To "fill" the totals, I can use multiples of 5, starting with 20, and going up to 100.  I have to use 6 discrete values to reach each total.  As an example, I can use 55x3, 30x2, and 25 as one possible permutation for 250, or 80x3 and 60x3 for 420.  I could also use 100, 95, 90,80, 30, and 25 for 420.

Obviously I could just find all the possible combinations by hand, but I figure there's probably an easier way.

What would you call this, and is there an easy way to write an equation to solve it?

Comment: look up knapsack problems.

Comment: For $(250)$ my approach would be to divide the total and all relevant terms by $(5)$.  This leaves filling $50$ with pieces of $~(11), (6),~$ and $(5)$.  Then, I would reason that the number of $(11)$ pieces must be some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  I would then explore the five cases separately.  This is a moderate compromise between analysis and brute force.